# Hi, I encounter a small question about matrix operation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence

Suppose an $n \times n$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $A$ and another sequence of $n \times n$ diagonal matrix $B^t$ whose diagonal elements $\epsilon^t_i>0$. As $t$ goes to infinity, all $\epsilon^t_i$ converge to zero (but still positive).

I want to show $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}A (A+B^t)^{-1} A = A$, but it seems extremely difficult. I can derive the result if $A$ is full-rank or the diagonal elements of $B^t$ are identical (i.e., $\epsilon_1^t=\dots=\epsilon_n^t$ for all $t$). However, I need to consider general cases where $A$ is not full rank and the diagonal elements of $B^t$ are not necessarily identical. Any nice bro can give me a hand? Many thanks!

My solution for the cases where $B^t$ has identical diagonal elements (i.e., $\epsilon^t$) is as follows.

I first do eigenvalue decomposition for $A=Q^T \Lambda Q$ with $\Lambda =\text{diag}([\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r,0,\dots,0])$. Then I have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
A(A+B^t)^{-1}A =& Q^T \Lambda Q(Q^T \Lambda Q+B^t)^{-1}Q^T \Lambda Q\\
=& Q^T \Lambda (\Lambda+B^t)^{-1} \Lambda Q\\
=& Q^T \Lambda\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{\lambda_{1}+\epsilon^t} & & & & &\\
        & \ddots & & & &\\
        & & \frac{1}{\lambda_{r}+\epsilon^t} & & &\\
        & & & 0 & &\\
        & & & & \ddots & \\
        & & & & & 0
    \end{bmatrix}\Lambda Q.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The last equality holds because the $j$-th column of $\Lambda$ with $j\geq r+1$ is zero and I can discard those corresponding diagonal elements in the big matrix. Then the result follows by letting $\epsilon^t$ go to 0.

However, if $B^t$ does not have identical diagonal elements, I do not have the second equality and the analysis is spoiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By diagonalising $A$, it is easy to see that $\lim_{\lambda\to0^+}A(A+\lambda I)^{-1}A$ exists and is equal to $A$.

Now, for any $\varepsilon>0$, pick some $\lambda>0$ such that $\|A-A(A+\lambda I)^{-1}A\|_2<\varepsilon$. Then pick some $T$ such that $\|B^t\|_2\le\lambda$ for all $t\ge T$. For each such $t$, we have $B^t \le \lambda I$ in the positive semidefinite partial ordering. In turn, we have
$$
\begin{align}
B^t \le \lambda I
&\implies A+B^t \le A+\lambda I\\
&\implies (A+B^t)^{-1} \ge (A+\lambda I)^{-1}\\
&\implies A^{1/2}(A+B^t)^{-1}A^{1/2} \ge A^{1/2}(A+\lambda I)^{-1}A^{1/2}.\tag{1}\\
\end{align}
$$
Recall that for any complex matrix $X$, the Gram matrices $XX^\ast$ and $X^\ast X$ have the same spectral norm. In particular, when $X=A^{1/2}(A+B^t)^{-1/2}$, since
$$
XX^\ast=(A+B^t)^{-1/2}A(A+B^t)^{-1/2}\le(A+B^t)^{-1/2}(A+B^t)(A+B^t)^{-1/2}=I,
$$
we also have $X^\ast X=A^{1/2}(A+B^t)^{-1}A^{1/2}\le I$. So, we may continue from $(1)$ to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
(1)
&\implies I \ge A^{1/2}(A+B^t)^{-1}A^{1/2} \ge A^{1/2}(A+\lambda I)^{-1}A^{1/2}\\
&\implies A \ge A(A+B^t)^{-1}A \ge A(A+\lambda I)^{-1}A\\
&\implies 0 \le A-A(A+B^t)^{-1}A \le A-A(A+\lambda I)^{-1}A\\
&\implies \|A-A(A+B^t)^{-1}A\|_2 \le \|A-A(A+\lambda I)^{-1}A\|_2<\varepsilon.\\
\end{align}
$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $\lim_{t\to\infty}A(A+B^t)^{-1}A=A$.

Comment: How does one formally see that $0\leq A - A(A+B^t)^{-1}A$?

Comment: Hi bro, I also do not quite understand why $0 \leq A - A(A+B^t)^{-1}A \leq A - A(A+\lambda I)^{-1} A$ holds. Could you please give more details about this step?

Comment: Bro, you are an amazing genius! Let me last check with you that, does $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\|A-A(A+B^t)^{-1}A\|_2=0$ necessary implies every elements of $A-A(A+B^t)^{-1}A$ converge to 0?

Comment: @MichaelD.Li [All norms are equivalent on a finite-dimensional vector space](https://planetmath.org/allnormsonfinitedimensionalvectorspacesareequivalent). They induce the same topology. If a sequence of matrices converges to a limit $L$ in one norm, it must also converge to $L$ in the other norm.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach using some elementary matrix identities which proves a slightly stronger result:

For $A$ symmetric positive semi-definite and $B_i$ invertible with $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} B_i=0$ and $(B_i+A)$ invertible for all $i$,

$$\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} A(B_i+A)^{-1}A =A.$$

Proof

For matrices $P$ and $Q$, $P + PQP = P(I + QP) = (I + PQ)P$

Hence if $I+QP$ is invertible then $(I + PQ)^{−1} P = P(I + QP)^{−1}$.

You can use this to show that for invertible $B$, $$D X^T (B+X D X^T)^{-1}X D = D X^T B^{-1} X (I+DX^T B^{-1} X)^{-1}D \tag{1}.$$

Now since $A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite $A$ has eigenvalue decomposition $A=XDX^T$.

Hence using (1), $A(B_i+A)^{-1}A = XDX^TB_i^{-1}X(I+DX^TB_i^{-1}X)^{-1}DX^T$

Now $DX^TB_i^{-1}X(I+DX^TB_i^{-1}X)^{-1}DX^T=(I+X^TB_i^{-1}X-I)(I+DX^TB_i^{-1}X)^{-1}DX^T=DX^T-(I+DX^TB_i^{-1}X)^{-1}DX^T$

But $(I+DX^TB_i^{-1}X)X^TB_i=(X^TB_i+DX^T)$ hence $X^TB_i=(I+DX^TB_i^{-1}X)^{-1}(X^TB_i+DX^T)$.

Taking the limit gives $\mathbb{0}=(\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}(I+DX^TB_i^{-1}X)^{-1})\; DX^T$.

Hence $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} DX^TB_i^{-1}X(I+DX^TB_i^{-1}X)^{-1}DX^T = DX^T$ and therefore $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} A(B_i+A)^{-1}A = XDX^T=A.$

Comment: Thanks! The stronger results give more insights into the problem I encountered.